# Why contravariant position in Builder is marked as invariant by compiler?

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I want to understand why scala compiler emits error for the following snippet:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable

class X[+A, +C] {
  val x = mutable.Map.empty[Int, mutable.Builder[A, C]]
}
```

The error ouput:

```
<console>:13: error: covariant type A occurs in invariant position in type => scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Builder[A,C]] of value x
       val x = mutable.Map.empty[Int, mutable.Builder[A, C]]
           ^
```

As I understand it, the variance rule is deduced outside-in like this:

1. `x` is at positive position.
2. type parameters of `mutable.Map.empty` is at neutral position.
3. Because of `2.` and variance annotation of `Builder[-Elem, +To]`, `A` is at negative position, and `C` is at positive position.

Therefore, `A` being covariant was misplaced in a negative (contravariant) position `-Elem`. Why does compiler say that it's an "invariant position"?

If I make `A` invariant, as in:

```scala
class X[A, +C] {
  val x = mutable.Map.empty[Int, mutable.Builder[A, C]]
}
```

The error became:

```
On line 2: error: covariant type C occurs in invariant position in type scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Builder[A,C]] of value x
```

I thought `C` position should have been positive (covariant), but compiler says it's also invariant?

Comment: because `Map` requires invariant types

Comment: I suppose it's because the value type of the mutable map is invariant. The second snippet compiles for immutable map, though. because the value type there is covariant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because value type of `Map` is invariant. The value type may appear both at covariant position (like in the return value of `get`) and contravariant position (like in the right hand side of `+=`).

If the compiler allows you to proceed, there will be type safety problem.

```scala
class A0
class A1 extends A0
class A2 extends A0

class C0
class C1 extends C0
class C2 extends C0

class X[+A, +C] {
  val x = mutable.Map.empty[Int, mutable.Builder[A, C]]   // won't compile
}

val x1: X[A1, C1] = new X[A1, C1]
val x2: X[A0, C0] = x1            // works because X[+A, +C]

x2.x += (new A2, new SomeBuilder[A0, C2])  // breaks type system
// we placed A2 as key, while the original x1 only accepts A1
// similar conflict happens for the value position
```

Comment: Type parameter of `mutable.Map` is in neutral/invariant position, so nested type's (in this case `Builder`) type parameter positions all became neutral/invariant, is that right?

Comment: Yes. For immutable Map[K, +V], you can have covariant type parameter in the value type.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to use the A, and C as genercis to val x.
The compiler does not know which type to use.

You can try the following:

```
trait A1
trait C1
class X[A <: A1, C <: C1] {
  val x = mutable.Map.empty[Int, mutable.Builder[A, C]]
}
```

Which will ensure that A and C are from the type you want.